# Auto reconnect postgresq database

Tags: python, postgresql

I have the following code:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="****", user="postgres", password="*****", host="localhost", port="5432")
print ("Opened database successfully")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''select * from xyz''')
print ("Table created successfully")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Like this i have some 50 -60 complex queries, but problem is some times the postgre sql Database throws the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ruw2/Desktop/SQL.py", line 87, in <module>
    cur.execute('''select * from xyz;''')
psycopg2.DatabaseError: server conn crashed?
server closed the connection unexpectedly. 
This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.
```

Looks like the connection is lost, how can i auto connect the Postgre database
Appreciate your help

Comment: It's hard to guess, most likely connection timed out, in which case most db adapters provide you a flag to automatically reconnect. Another option is that server really crashed, in which case check the logs; Yet another is that internet is flaky between your client and db server (if localhost:5432 is forwarded somewhere). Yet another possibility is deadlock (unlikely), or that result set is so large that server or client dies (try newer versions).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when i run this manually it runs fine, but when i run it through Python code to automate it will end up with the error. Is there any auto reconnect options...

Comment: You lost me at "Python code to automate." It seems you have bigger problems...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Catch the exception and reconnect:

```
while True:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="****", user="postgres", password="*****", host="localhost", port="5432")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute('''select * from xyz''')
    except psycopg2.OperationalError:
        continue
    break;
```

Comment: So if i use the above code and if exception occurs then will it go back to try block again and perform the task.  Basically i want to reconnect in case of exception and execute the required queries.Thanks for your response.

Comment: It won't go back to the try block. Instead, it'll go back to the beginning of the `while` loop.

Comment: @IrfanAhmed As @Mike commented it will restart the `while loop` and will redo the connection.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto@mike lawson @ All, Thanks for your advice , it works

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. I think OperationalError is not a good exception to catch and retry. Some of its subclasses do but others have no chance of succeeding just by retrying. To be 100% correct, you may have to catch psycopg2.Error and check its pgcode against a list of error codes that you have to exhaustively prepare by yourself.

Answer (score 13):

I would rely on decorators - [retry](https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#retry-functions) and reconnect:

```py
import psycopg2
from tenacity import retry, wait_exponential, stop_after_attempt
from typing import Callable

def reconnect(f: Callable):
    def wrapper(storage: DbStorage, *args, **kwargs):
        if not storage.connected():
            storage.connect()

        try:
            return f(storage, *args, **kwargs)
        except psycopg2.Error:
            storage.close()
            raise

    return wrapper


class DbStorage:

    def __init__(self, conn: string):
        self._conn: string = conn
        self._connection = None

    def connected(self) -> bool:
        return self._connection and self._connection.closed == 0

    def connect(self):
        self.close()
        self._connection = psycopg2.connect(self._conn)

    def close(self):
        if self.connected():
            # noinspection PyBroadException
            try:
                self._connection.close()
            except Exception:
                pass

        self._connection = None

    @retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(3), wait=wait_exponential())
    @reconnect
    def get_data(self): # pass here required params to get data from DB
        # ..
        cur = self._connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('''select * from xyz''')
        # ..
```

Comment: i am getting the error: "NameError: name 'DbStorage' is not defined" under the "def wrapper(storage: DbStorage..."  obvious the class DbStorage is after the reconnect.  how to fix this.  i'm using Python 3.7.3.